# unslugifying the already slugified text in django without using replace method

Tags: django, django-templates

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
urlparameter = slugify("This is my First trip")
# this-is-my-first-trip
```

now i want it to un-slugify it
to previous text ('this is my first trip') but not using `replace.("-", " ")`

Is there any django way to do so ??

Comment: You can not unslugify, since `slugify` is a non-bijective function.

Answer (score 0):

No built in way to do it, by design.

slugify is not a bijective function, e.g. you can't always get back to the input from the output.

e.g.

```
   slugify("A B")   > "a-b
   slugify("A - b") > "a-b"
```

If you were trying to turn "a-b" back into orig text, which one is it?

If source of your slugs is very controlled then replace("-", " ") may work for you, or you may be better with `urllib.parse.quote` and `urllib.parse.unquote`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html